# Script Error Exception in IIS6

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I'm getting a Script Error Exception randomly from a classic asp site we're running on  IIS6 Server 2003.  The error I see in the Event Viewer is:

Error: Script Engine Exception. A ScriptEngine threw exception 'C0000005' in 'IScriptDispatchEx::Release()' from 'CScriptingNamespace::UnInit()'..

We're gotten this error two days in a row now and both times its caused our sites on that server to freeze up and quit working.  We then have to Restart IIS to get the sites to come back up.  I've dug around in our log files and nothing out of the ordinary seems to be happening at the time this error is thrown.

Was wondering if anyone else has come across this error and what could be causing it, or if someone could point me in the right direction to detect what is causing this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do any of your scripts write to files on the server? If so, check those files + directories are writeable by NETWORK_SERVICE and IIS_USRS, do you use compression? Low on disk space?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, we're currently digging into the issue more and see if we can figure it out.

Comment: I don't like leaving his open, we figured out the issue had to do with some jscript on a page another developer had worked on.  Luckily we're ridding our servers of classic asp but it did have something to do with authentication so I'm going to give BugFinder credit for this one ;)